# pretty print assertEqual() for HTML strings

Tags: python, html, unit-testing, testing

I want to compare two strings in a python unittest which contain html.

Is there a method which outputs the result in a human friendly (diff like) version?

Comment: Django has assertHTMLEqual since version 1.4: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertHTMLEqual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I (the one asking this question) use BeautfulSoup now:

```
def assertEqualHTML(string1, string2, file1='', file2=''):
    u'''
    Compare two unicode strings containing HTML.
    A human friendly diff goes to logging.error() if there
    are not equal, and an exception gets raised.
    '''
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs
    import difflib
    def short(mystr):
        max=20
        if len(mystr)>max:
            return mystr[:max]
        return mystr
    p=[]
    for mystr, file in [(string1, file1), (string2, file2)]:
        if not isinstance(mystr, unicode):
            raise Exception(u'string ist not unicode: %r %s' % (short(mystr), file))
        soup=bs(mystr)
        pretty=soup.prettify()
        p.append(pretty)
    if p[0]!=p[1]:
        for line in difflib.unified_diff(p[0].splitlines(), p[1].splitlines(), fromfile=file1, tofile=file2):
            logging.error(line)
        raise Exception('Not equal %s %s' % (file1, file2))
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple method is to strip whitespace from the HTML and split it into a list. [Python 2.7's unittest](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html) (or the backported [unittest2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2)) then gives a human-readable diff between the lists.

```
import re

def split_html(html):
    return re.split(r'\s*\n\s*', html.strip())

def test_render_html():
    expected = ['<div>', '...', '</div>']
    got = split_html(render_html())
    self.assertEqual(expected, got)
```

If I'm writing a test for working code, I usually first set `expected = []`, insert a `self.maxDiff = None` before the assert and let the test fail once. The expected list can then be copy-pasted from the test output.

You might need to tweak how whitespace is stripped depending on what your HTML looks like.

Answer (score 2):

I submitted a patch to do this some years back. The patch was rejected but you can still view it on the [python bug list](http://bugs.python.org/issue725569).

I doubt you would want to hack your unittest.py to apply the patch (if it even still works after all this time), but here's the function for reducing two strings a manageable size while still keeping at least part of what differs. So long as all you didn't want the complete differences this *might* be what you want:

```
def shortdiff(x,y):
    '''shortdiff(x,y)

    Compare strings x and y and display differences.
    If the strings are too long, shorten them to fit
    in one line, while still keeping at least some difference.
    '''
    import difflib
    LINELEN = 79
    def limit(s):
        if len(s) > LINELEN:
            return s[:LINELEN-3] + '...'
        return s

    def firstdiff(s, t):
        span = 1000
        for pos in range(0, max(len(s), len(t)), span):
            if s[pos:pos+span] != t[pos:pos+span]:
                for index in range(pos, pos+span):
                    if s[index:index+1] != t[index:index+1]:
                        return index

    left = LINELEN/4
    index = firstdiff(x, y)
    if index > left + 7:
        x = x[:left] + '...' + x[index-4:index+LINELEN]
        y = y[:left] + '...' + y[index-4:index+LINELEN]
    else:
        x, y = x[:LINELEN+1], y[:LINELEN+1]
        left = 0

    cruncher = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None)
    xtags = ytags = ""
    cruncher.set_seqs(x, y)
    editchars = { 'replace': ('^', '^'),
                  'delete': ('-', ''),
                  'insert': ('', '+'),
                  'equal': (' ',' ') }
    for tag, xi1, xi2, yj1, yj2 in cruncher.get_opcodes():
        lx, ly = xi2 - xi1, yj2 - yj1
        edits = editchars[tag]
        xtags += edits[0] * lx
        ytags += edits[1] * ly

    # Include ellipsis in edits line.
    if left:
        xtags = xtags[:left] + '...' + xtags[left+3:]
        ytags = ytags[:left] + '...' + ytags[left+3:]

    diffs = [ x, xtags, y, ytags ]
    if max([len(s) for s in diffs]) < LINELEN:
        return '\n'.join(diffs)

    diffs = [ limit(s) for s in diffs ]
    return '\n'.join(diffs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a quite 'verbose' solution. You could add a new 'equality function' for your user defined type (e.g: `HTMLString`) which you have to define first:

```
class HTMLString(str):
    pass
```

Now you have to define a type equality function:

```
def assertHTMLStringEqual(first, second):
    if first != second:
        message = ... # TODO here: format your message, e.g a diff
        raise AssertionError(message)
```

All you have to do is format your message as you like. You can also use a class method in your specific `TestCase` as a type equality function. This gives you more functionality to format your message, since `unittest.TestCase` does this a lot.

Now you have to register this equality function in your `unittest.TestCase`:

```
...
def __init__(self):
    self.addTypeEqualityFunc(HTMLString, assertHTMLStringEqual)
```

The same for a class method:

```
...
def __init__(self):
    self.addTypeEqualityFunc(HTMLString, 'assertHTMLStringEqual')
```

And now you can use it in your tests:

```
def test_something(self):
    htmlstring1 = HTMLString(...)
    htmlstring2 = HTMLString(...)
    self.assertEqual(htmlstring1, htmlstring2)
```

This should work well with python 2.7.